# Using a variable in MySQL Select Statment in a Where Clause

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I would like to know if it's possible to find a value in a select statement and use it in a where clause like:

```
SELECT col1, MAX(col2) - COUNT(DISTINCT col3) as variable
FROM table
WHERE col1 > variable
```

"table" is pretty big, and I want to narrow down the records the query has to look at as quickly as possible.

I know this isn't bit of code isn't possible as written (#1054 - Unknown column 'variable' in 'where clause'), but is there anyway to figure out the value of "variable" and then use it in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try subquery syntax, also called nested select.

I think something like:

```
SELECT col1 WHERE col1 > (SELECT MAX(col2) - COUNT(DISTINCT col3))
```

See the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) for some better examples.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can replicate an expression in a WHERE clause, as demonstrated by RedFilter. In other cases, this isn't possible and you can use a HAVING clause, e.g.

```
SELECT col1, MAX(col2) - COUNT(DISTINCT col3) as variable
FROM table
HAVING col1 > variable
```

HAVING is less efficient, think of it as a resultset post-processor rather than something the query optimizer can do anything with.