# Shouldn't this sql query (where after combining colums) work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
Select (Country.Name + ', ' + City.Name) as Location
...
Where Location like '%Punta Cana%'
```

Since it works without the 'where' I naively assumed it could just work. Well, it doesn't and throws the error: Invalid column name 'Location'. Does anyone has the time to please explain why doesn't it work and what would be the working alternative?

Comment: Agreed, it's definitely a duplicate. Thanks for the answer btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this approach instead:

```
; with temp as (
Select (Country.Name + ', ' + City.Name) as Location
...
)
select * from temp
Where Location like '%Punta Cana%'
```

Comment: Good stuff, still can't decide on which to mark as the correct answer :P

Comment: Whichever you implemented in your code :)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not refer to column aliases anywhere else in the query except `ORDER BY`. This is because of the way the clauses in the query are logically parsed by SQL Server - `SELECT` is second last. ([Lots of interesting discussion about this over on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19762/why-is-the-select-clause-listed-first/).)

Your options are to repeat the expression or use a subquery / CTE. There are already examples of subquery / CTE, so just for completeness, you could also do:

```
Select (Country.Name + ', ' + City.Name) as Location
...
Where (Country.Name + ', ' + City.Name) like '%Punta Cana%'
```

I just answered this same question yesterday, including proving that repeating the expression is not as expensive as it sounds:

[Reference alias (calculated in SELECT) in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182339/reference-alias-calculated-in-select-in-where-clause/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the alias in the `ORDER BY` you can wrap the entire `SELECT` inside of another `SELECT`

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    Select (Country.Name + ', ' + City.Name) as Location
    ...
) x
Where x.Location like '%Punta Cana%'
```

Otherwise you will have to use the expression again in the `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score 0):

Location is not the column name. Its just an Alias that you are creating.