# search for fullname on joined table

Tags: mysql

I've written a query to search by fullname on join table but I get this error. any idea?

```
SELECT wrs.id, wrs.fname, wrs.sname, wrs.email1, wrs.applied, wrs.firstlogin, wrs.tel1,
       SUBSTR( wrs.lastlogin, -10 ) AS last_login, 
       CONCAT_WS(  ' ', wrs.fname, wrs.sname ) AS full_name, wqs.level, 
       wqs.subject, wqs.university, wqs.dissertation
FROM temp_users AS wrs
    LEFT JOIN writer_qualifications AS wqs ON wqs.writer_id = wrs.id
WHERE wrs.fname LIKE  '%micky%'
   OR wrs.sname LIKE  '%micky%'
   OR full_name LIKE  '%micky%'
   AND wrs.status =  '1'
GROUP BY wrs.id


MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'full_name' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: for `OR full_name LIKE  '%micky%'` to be true, either of `wrs.fname LIKE  '%micky%'` and `wrs.sname LIKE  '%micky%` would already be true

Comment: Thank you Ejay. What do you mean by qualify

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182339/reference-alias-calculated-in-select-in-where-clause

Comment: @IsaacRajaei edited comment for clarity. I mean to say that you might not need to test `full_name`

Comment: is there any idea how to search for full name for this query?

Comment: @Ejay if you search for "full name" it wont be buddy

Comment: @IsaacRajaei ah, you're right :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an alias name like `full_name` in the WHERE clause, see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html)

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

so you've got to use the expression `CONCAT_WS(  ' ', wrs.fname, wrs.sname )` in the WHERE clause instead of the alias `full_name`:

```
SELECT wrs.id, wrs.fname, wrs.sname, wrs.email1, wrs.applied, wrs.firstlogin, wrs.tel1,
   SUBSTR( wrs.lastlogin, -10 ) AS last_login, 
   CONCAT_WS(  ' ', wrs.fname, wrs.sname ) AS full_name, wqs.level, 
   wqs.subject, wqs.university, wqs.dissertation
FROM temp_users AS wrs
    LEFT JOIN writer_qualifications AS wqs ON wqs.writer_id = wrs.id
WHERE wrs.fname LIKE  '%micky%'
    OR wrs.sname LIKE  '%micky%'
    OR CONCAT_WS(  ' ', wrs.fname, wrs.sname ) LIKE  '%micky%'
    AND wrs.status =  '1'
GROUP BY wrs.id
```

Comment: what do you suggest then? what is this?!! OR CONCAT_WS(  ' ', wrs.fname, wrs.sname ) LIKE  '%micky%'

Comment: Yes, the same construct that you use for your `full_name` instead of the alias name `full_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an alias of an aggregate ('full_name') in a WHERE clause because the server typically processes the WHERE clause before it does the aggregate work.  This question/answer has great options and explanations for you: [Reference alias (calculated in SELECT) in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182339/reference-alias-calculated-in-select-in-where-clause)