# Ordering by expression from Select

Tags: sql, sybase

I need to make a query like this:

```
SELECT (t.a-t.b) AS 'difference'
FROM t
ORDER BY abs(t.a-t.b)
```

Is there a way not to duplicate code (t.a-t.b) ? Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the SQL statement and then perform the ORDER BY if you're performing an absolute value on it.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT (t.a-t.b) AS "difference"
   FROM t
) a
ORDER BY abs(a.difference)
```

UPDATE: I used SQL Server the 1st time, but depending on your environment (Oracle, MySQL), you may need to include double quotes around the column alias, so:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT (t.a-t.b) AS "difference"
   FROM t
) a
ORDER BY abs("a.difference")
```

Comment: If you want to read more about it this is a very similar post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182339/reference-alias-calculated-in-select-in-where-clause

Comment: Please see my comment for #1 answer:  it says : "invalid column name: difference"

Comment: Works for me, but try prefacing the column with 'a', so 'abs(a.difference)'.

Comment: Added an update about including double quotes around column alias.  Let me know if you're still having trouble.

Comment: That's all right now, thank you. Quotes not needed in parameter of abs(). Maybe I was doing something wrong before