# How can I use a created column as a filter

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure a work around for this query I am writing in SQL Server.

I need to be able to use the results from the `CASE` statement in the `DateDiff` function.

- If the encounter end date is null then I want to use the encounter begin date for the date diff calculation.
- If the encounter end date is not null then I want to use the encounter end date for the date diff calculation.

However, I keep getting an "invalid column name" error when I put the `dateofservice` in the `datediff` function.

This is my code:

```
Select 
    e.encounterid,
    Case 
        when e.encounterenddate = null
            then e.encounterbegindate
        else e.encounterenddate
    end as dateofservice,
    rf.submissiondate,
    datediff(day, dateofservice, rf.submissiondate) as lagtime,
    rf.healthplancode,
    rf.transactiontypeid
from 
    udt_encounter as E
join 
    udt_receivedfile as RF on e.receivedfileid = rf.receivedfileid
where 
    rf.healthplancode = '00'
    and rf.transactiontypeid = 1
    and rf.submissiondate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-06-30'
order by 
    encounter.id asc
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference alias (calculated in SELECT) in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182339/reference-alias-calculated-in-select-in-where-clause)

Comment: Your use of checking if something is null is incorrect: `when e.encounterenddate=null` would never be satisfied. You should use `when e.encounterenddate IS NULL` . Having said that @KekeSemau's answer is a btter way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You do not even need `CASE`, `COALESCE` will do it.
Since this is quite short I would stick with simply repeating the expression:

```
SELECT 
    e.encounterid,
    COALESCE(e.encounterenddate, e.encounterbegindate) AS dateofservice
    ,rf.submissiondate
    ,datediff(day, COALESCE(e.encounterenddate, e.encounterbegindate), rf.submissiondate) AS lagtime
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for the input.  I've been using SQL Server/SQL for literally 2 weeks.  Learning on the fly from YouTube.

Comment: @atdower Great, good luck! If this has answered your question, please 'accept' it with the checkmark button.